# Rails form with custom path & getting missing required ID key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I know I'm breaking Rails convention somehow which is causing the error, but I can't figure out what...

```
# controller
def membership
   @user = User.new(user_type:"member")
end
def membership_create
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   ...
end

# routes
match '/membership/create.:id', to: "users#membership_create", via: :post, as: "create_member"

# view
# have tried the following based on various other answers, doesn't work
<%= form_for @user, :url => create_member_path(@user), method: :post do |f| %>
<%= form_for @user, :url => create_member_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

Consistently getting the error message: `No route matches {:action=>"membership_create", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: slash instead dot `match '/membership/create/:id', to: "users#membership_create", via: :post, as: "create_member"`

Comment: You need ID in your routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `/membership/create/:id` as opposed to `/membership/create.:id`?

But then, you are just building a new user from your membership method:

```
def membership
  @user = User.new(user_type:"member")
end
```

And this user has no `id` yet. So, when you are passing it into the path for your form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => create_member_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

The `id` is `nil`.

However, your `membership_create` requires an `id`? - ( as configured in the route ) Remember this will be nil at this point. Unless you have miraculously included an `id` somewhere in the loop, which I can't see, or this two methods are not directly related like I think.

Comment: omg... i just copied the default scaffold code wrong... ok shoot me